# How to "Link App" to existing Client ID and prodcution SHA1 when publishing Alpha new Android Game

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have completed the development and testing of my new Android Game that uses google-play services. such as AppState, Google Plus sign in, achievements, & leaderboards. I have been testing on numerous devices with numerous tester accounts all set up correctly within the Google Play Developer and Google API console.

My testing APK was signed with my standard eclipse debug keystore.

I am now ready to start Alpha testing. i have signed my APK with my production keystore and uploaded it successfully.

I have set up a google community for my Alpha testers, however none of my testers can sign into my published Alpha game.

they receive a pop up message saying "The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information"

How do i link the Alpha APK with the production SHA1 key?

Do i have to delete the current linked game and re add it using my production SHA1?

or can i have duplicate linked apps for the same game, one linked to me test debug SHA1, the other linked to my production SHA1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add up to 20 keys for each game service.

Follow the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) to **add** the SHA1 for the key you used to sign your Alpha APK.

Comment: free3dom thanks for taking the time to look at my issue. I dont think this will resolve my problem. When i was setting up the linked app to my game services i only added my debug SHA1 key. How can i now add my production SHA1?

Comment: In the developer console, go to `Game services`, then select you game/app, then select `Linked apps`. Now just choose `Link another app` to add more apps to your service - you can link multiple instances of the same app, but with different signing certificates :)

Comment: when i try this approach i dont get the chnce to enter my SHA1, the additional linked app automatically picks up the original client id. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I dpn't know...when I add a new linked app it takes me through the whole Authorization phase again (as described [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#b_create_a_client_id)) and that allows me to specify a new SHA1.

Comment: Thanks again, i have now fixed this by linking the same app for the second time and publishing it and it all working fine, nice one

Comment: You should get the chance to enter your Release SHA1. You get a default value, but you can overwrite it. It is confusing, I know.